# How can I delete all the text from text file in c?

Tags: c, file, fopen

given argument `fd`  in type of `FILE*` , for example:
`FILE* fd = fopen("a.txt","w")`.

How can I delete all the text that writed in `a.txt`?

**NOTE: I don't know what is the name of the file (I am write a function that gets argument in type of `FILE*` that someone already opened in the main).**

---

For example:

```
FILE* fd = fopen("a.txt","w");
assert(fd != NULL); // it's not important for this question.  
fprintf(fd,"hello1\n");
fprintf(fd,"hello2\n");
//.... and now I want to remove all the text from a.txt. How can I do it?
//     The cleaning will be in other function that get just fd (without the 
//     name of the file)
fclose(fd);
```

Comment: `freopen` will do the job

Comment: Can I do it in some way with print "" (and without open the file again?)

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I edited my question.

Comment: @Software_t: Which changes everything (invalidates the answer, but makes the question interesting).

Comment: @Bathsheba After that I saw the answer I understood that it's important point (I was sure that exists some way by print empty string to the file or something like that).

Comment: Maybe try `frewind()` or `fsetpos()`?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp It's just `rewind`; been that way since ANSI C 89.

Comment: @Software_t: in what context and kind of program, and on what operating system, do you want to do that? It seems *very wrong* and *error-prone*. Please **edit your question** to explain more

Comment: @Kaz Thanks. I don't use those functions much. I just tried it and it doesn't seem to work anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can open it with the `write` flag

```
fopen(filename, "w")
```

the file would be overwritten with a new empty file if already exists.

Comment: Can I do it in some way with print "" (and without open the file again?)

Comment: @Software_t Not by using just the functions that are in ISO C standard.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ftruncate` on most systems except Windows. Windows has the `_chsize` function. You have to do some preprocessor checks:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#include <io.h>
#else
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#endif

int truncate_file(FILE *fp);

#ifdef _WIN32
int truncate_file(FILE *fp) {
    return _chsize(_fileno(fp), 0);
}
#else
int truncate_file(FILE *fp) {
    return ftruncate(fileno(fp), 0);
}
#endif
```

I'm not sure whether this is quite correct on Cygwin or MinGW.

However, if you want to write clean, portable code without a bunch of preprocessor use, your only option is to reopen the file:

```
FILE *fp;
...
fclose(fp);
fp = fopen(filename, "w");
fclose(fp);
```

Comment: `ftruncate` is suported on Windows. Firstly, Microsoft has it in their Visual C run-time library under almost the same interface; they just renamed it to `_chsize`. `ftruncate` is also in Cygwin and therefore [Cygnal](http://www.kylheku.com/cygnal/).

Comment: Visual C: `_chsize(_fileno(fp), 0)`.  The size argument is a `long` rather than `off_t`.

Comment: @Kaz: Yes, equivalent functionality is available on Windows. But it's a function with a different name in a different header file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ftruncate` function to truncate an open file.  Documentation here:

https://linux.die.net/man/2/truncate

```
ftruncate(fileno(fd), 0);
```

Comment: Better call `fflush` before, see my answer why

Answer (score 1):

Either close and reopen the file (as suggested in [Kira Sama's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50451533/841108)), or, *on POSIX systems* use [truncate(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/truncate.2.html)

However, if you do that, the `FILE*` handle is out of sync (and you need to at last [fflush(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html) -bercause `FILE*` are *buffered*- before the `truncate`, and not use the same `FILE*` without any [freopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/freopen.3.html)...). With pure standard C11 (see [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)) there is no way of doing what you want.

In practice, if you use `truncate`, you should avoid `<stdio.h>` functions and use [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) and [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) directly.

Perhaps higher level libraries like [sqlite](http://sqlite.org/) or [gdbm](https://www.gnu.org.ua/software/gdbm/) could interest you.

> I don't know what is the name of the file (I am write a function that gets argument in type of FILE* that someone already opened in the main).

Then I believe **you should not do what you want.** (On some POSIX systems, you might use [fileno(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fileno.3.html) and then `ftruncate`, but by doing so you are violating some invariants from `<stdio.h>` and messing up your `FILE*`)

Look also into [rewind(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/rewind.3.html) & fseek(3)

Answer (score 1):

There is no *portable* way of doing this in C.

In C, the interactions with files are via *streams*, and no facility exists to remove something from a stream as that makes no real sense. A `FILE*` is a pointer to an intentionally opaque structure.

I'd be tempted to deal with this at the calling site that sets the `FILE*` in the first place.